# display only one language when displaying specific post QTranslate

Tags: wordpress, qtranslate

I'm using the following code to display the content of the post with PostID of 4:

```
<?php $post_id = 4; $queried_post = get_post($post_id); echo $queried_post->post_content; ?>
```

However this is code is displaying the content of both languages I have defined with Qtranslate. How can I make it show only the content of the language it is set on.

Thanks!

Comment: How did you define both languages with qTranslate? You should have shown the example so that answerers could get the idea where you did wrong.

Answer (score 0):

If I've understood you correctly, you should be able to run the content through the `__()` or `_e()` function to have qTranslate extract the content for the current language.  So

```
<?php
$post_id = 4;
$queried_post = get_post($post_id);
_e($queried_post->post_content);
?>
```

should do the trick